# Upload file to folder - angular

Tags: angularjs, file-upload

I am trying to upload file to network folder.  Can we do this in angular ?

Do we need to create web api ( rest web service) for this?

Thanks

Comment: Of course you can upload. Beyond that this question is far too broad

Comment: Do we need to have rest web service for that?

Comment: not specifically no...just an endpoint that is expecting uploaded files

Comment: Do you have an code sample; if so, could you please share that ?

Comment: $http({
            url: " network folder ",
            method: "POST",
            data: data,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        }).success(function (response) {
            callback(response);
        });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a web server of some kind for this. It doesn't need to be a REST service.

There is an npm module that does this:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload

Some assembly required :)